# #1062 - Duplicate entry '31' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql

**php error:**

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '31' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**query:**

```
INSERT INTO `calls`(
    `id`, `number`, `type`, `charges`, `duration`, `date`, `c_number`
)
VALUES (31,'03227453033','onnet',2,1,'2012-12-06','03216196069')
```

`id` is my primary key and its auto incremented. Currently there are 30 rows in my database 
table.

Comment: The "next record" counter may be higher, though. Remember, there may be deleted records, one of which previously occupied the ID `31`

Comment: *Do not confuse an auto-increment key value with a "row number".* Auto-incremenet keys may lead to sparse numbers (e.g. deleted rows, rolled back transactions, different start/step) - anyway, the key *does* exist, so find out why (and better, let it do it's magic auto-incremenet).

Comment: If the `id` is auto incremented, exclude it from the insert statement.

Comment: @marram: Why would anyone use a Pakistani mobile number in a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > INSERT INTO `calls`(`number`, `type`, `charges`, `duration`, `date`, `c_number`) VALUES ('03227453033','onnet',2,1,'2012-12-06','03216196069')

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

For an auto-increment field, you leave it out of a SQL insert query as mysql will auto-populate it. Only do this if it is defined as an auto-increment field.

```
INSERT INTO `calls`(`number`, `type`, `charges`, `duration`, `date`, `c_number`)
VALUES ('03227453033' ,'onnet', 2, 1, '2012-12-06', '03216196069')
```

Comment: #1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'... now got this error

Comment: Are you sure you've set `ID` to Primary key and auto-increment?

Comment: If you've been inserting your IDs manually since creating the table, you may need to manually set the auto-increment value in the `information_schema` database. Find out what the highest ID value you have (for instance 32). Then you need to go to the `information_schema` database and run the following: `UPDATE \`TABLES\` SET \`AUTO_INCREMENT\`=[Highest ID value +1] WHERE \`TABLE_SCHEMA\`='[databaseName]' AND \`TABLE_NAME\`='[tableName]' LIMIT 1` Obviously change the values between square quotes `[ ]` to the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is auto incremented, then you shouldn't normally include it in your `INSERT` statement. It seems that you already have a row with id 31.